# Laravel 5.2 - adding page title to URL

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I have a project like amazon based on Laravel 5.2.

I need to show title of product and category in URL of page which preview with only ID.

For example:

```
ID: 2
Name: Apple iPhone 6s
```

The URL: www.mysite.com/showproduct/2

I need this to be: www.mysite.com/showproduct/2-Apple-IPhone-6s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look to Laravel 5.2 documentation especially **[Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters)** part, you will notice a red box there say :

> **Note:** Route parameters cannot contain the - character. Use an underscore (_) instead.

So your route could be:

```
Route::get('showproduct/{title}', 'Controller@action');
```

But instead of `2-Apple-IPhone-6s` it should be `2_Apple_IPhone_6s`, IMO better if you could use it as:

```
Route::get('showproduct/{id}/{title?}', 'Controller@action');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, route paramters must be in the format, but Route parameters are not the url slug that may be used. I use the - in my slugs all of the time.

Comment: thanks it's what i need (Y) it take the title as save in database but no problem it's fine

Comment: @AndrewNolan thanks for your intervention.. no needs for slugs in this case he just use direct routes.

Comment: Very nice and useful. Thanks @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Glad I could help brother

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Don't make the wheel again ;)